# What proportion of human work is strictly productive?

Tags: workforce

I'd like to ask about work, being "human labour" or "use of human time" or maybe partly "the expending of economic and human resources". For this question I'm going to divide work into four types, below.

`Type I` - Some work directly produces things that are necessary for survival, such as farming, building homes, making clothing, medical care, &c. I would say that this kind of work makes the "pie"; without it, there's fundamentally nothing.

`Type II` - Some work enables or augments directly productive work without being strictly productive itself, such as managing a farming company, doing R&D on building techniques, and investing to maximise productive output, &c. I would say that this kind of work makes the "pie" bigger; it can be a force multiplier, but it couldn't be done without Type I.

`Type III` - Some work simply aims to enrich, without either producing anything or enabling production. It's difficult to create pure examples of this, but things like predatory lending, advertising, rent-seeking, lobbying, middle-manning, &c, seem to fit the bill. Much of them will, in some capacity, still improve or enable some kind of production, but the defining qualities would be the intent and the overall trend or impact of the activity. This type of work just tries to get a bigger piece of the "pie", even if the pie shrinks overall.

`Type IV` - Some work is creative (or consumptive), and seeks to make things that people want, or which people want to make.  Where it's benign we get culture, and where it's malignant we get consumer culture. This isn't really the focus of this question, but incidentally I believe that creative work is the most important and significant thing for human beings. Whether this should be "work" or the thing that work frees us to do for ourselves is also a separate question. If we talk about the "pie" here, this would be the stuff for which the pie was made, and is basically just consuming the pie. Yes, the pie gets eaten. But what is it there for otherwise?

---

In the ancient world, `Type I` seems to have taken up the lion's share of human work. There was presumably a time when every individual was involved full-time in producing food, housing, clothing, medicine (such as it was), and other basic necessities.

But now `Type I` seems to be a much, much smaller proportion of the whole. Does it take so many as 1 farmer to feed 1,000 others? And waste, as in `Type III`, seems to [run rampant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bullshit_Jobs). I'm sorry to fabricate a number from thin air, but getting some harder figures is basically the point of this question.

Which is to say; despite the ambiguous nature of the categories I've given above (especially between types II and III), is there any data or explorations of the proportion or amount of work there is that falls into each of these categories? In "first world" countries? In the world at large?

The underlying question which I have is thus: how much of modern work, or the modern economy, is just culture? How much of it could be called unnecesary, or wasteful?

Perhaps my question is nonsense, or simply not right for Economics. If so, I apologize.

Comment: Your question is not nonsense.  In fact, your distinction of types of labour has a certain similarity with that drawn by Smith in _The Wealth of Nations_ between productive and unproductive labour - see [here](https://www.econlib.org/library/Smith/smWN.html?chapter_num=18#book-reader).

Answer (score 1):

> The underlying question which I have is thus: how much of modern work, or the modern economy, is just culture?

According to [OECD](https://www.oecd.org/cfe/notetojournalists-culture-english.htm#:%7E:text=Despite%20culture%20being%20in,government%20spending%20across%20the%20OECD.) household spending on culture is on average about 3.8%, and governments additional 1.2%.

So about 5% on average but of course it ranges, in some countries like Iceland it would be above that in some below that.

> How much of it could be called unnecessary, or wasteful?

None when it comes to culture. Purpose of an economy is to produce what people want. There is no economic difference between producing shirt and an opera. Both are produced to satisfy human needs one is for covering your body other is for cultural fulfilment.

What can be considered wasteful are *some* of the examples of what you call type III  (although not all would qualify). More specifically, rent seeking, the practice of manipulating public policy or economic conditions to gain wealth without  any reciprocal contribution of productivity, is waste for economy.

In addition, government policies or market failures that lead to dead-weight loss can be considered wasteful as in presence of either of the above society could have more welfare by correcting the policy or market failure.

Also waste cannot be measured as % of current spending, since macroeconomically \$1 of spending is \$1 that further circulates in the economy regardless where it is spent. Rather, you have to compare potential economy without spending that 1 dollar on rent seeking compared to actual economy where the 1 dollar is wasted on rent seeking.

There is no good statistics for deadweight loss for economy as whole, when it comes to rent seeking I know of no global estimates, but in the US it is [estimated](https://www.mercatus.org/publications/government-spending/cost-rent-seeking-actual-and-potential-economic-growth) that US economy could have been 28% larger without engaging in it.

Comment: I realized that I had been misleading with that sentence just about as quickly as I had posted the question, but I have a strange impression that editing questions for small things is frowned upon on StackExchange. What I meant by "how much of modern work is just culture" was to ask specifically, "how much of modern work is the result of a cultural history that encourages self interested competition at the exepense of various commons?"

Comment: @user17728431 that would be substantial edit as it would change whole meaning of question so yes that is frowned upon. Also, commons are defined as natural resources available to all (air, seas, some lakes etc) so its unclear what that even means, also how do you define cultural history? Depending on how you define commons and cultural history I am not even sure if its economics question anymore

Comment: @1muflon1 I can see it having that meaning originally. i.e. what percentage of work is useful, and what percentage is just work culture = the culture of everyone having to work a lot.

Comment: I don't think the culture of having to work a lot even exists in many countries. In the Netherlands, about 50 of all employed person work part time according to [Eurostat](https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/web/products-eurostat-news/-/DDN-20180608-1). If that is voluntary or not doesn't even matter in this context because if it were a culture of having to work a lot, this would not exist. I also think it's a far stretch to assume most work is useless.

Comment: @Alex *I also think it's a far stretch to assume most work is useless.*
That's why I've asked this question.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote...

> The underlying question which I have is thus: how much of modern work,
> or the modern economy, is just culture? How much of it could be called
> unnecesary, or wasteful?

You seem to be drawing a distinction between "strictly productive" and "just culture". I think the distinction is flawed and I will elaborate.

Viewing work through a culture lens is not very useful. I don't care if the OECD has classified some expenditure as culture spending. In Northern European culture people eat a lot of potatoes. In Asia they eat rice. These product choices are associated with their respective cultures so these products are forms of cultural output and cultural consumption. If you didn't consume the products of culture you wouldn't survive so culture falls into your Type 1 category. If this is not what you expected, then maybe there is a problem with your classification system. Your Type 4 category says it is to include "things that people want" which is literally everything that people spend money on so again your classification system does not make sense.

Unnecessary work seems identifiable in retrospect. Inventory that is thrown away represents unnecessary work performed. Perishables discarded probably don't count since we can determine ahead of time how much is likely to be discarded, the whole should have a discounted value from the start. In other words, a certain amount of necessary work is required to produce some percentage of the bananas that will be discarded because it's more practical to discard some bananas than to invest in the perfect distribution system. A company that produced unsellable clothing or hardware or software produced unnecessary work. Since there is uncertainty, the economy will produce some unnecessary work that is recognized as unnecessary after it was produced.  Accounting valuation changes might be a measure of this however accounts sometimes use historical values where there is no practical way to determine the market value so it's not perfect. The more uncertainty there is in value, the more unnecessary work will be produced.